# error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'std::list<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>> *'to 'std::string*'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm currently learning how to use lists in C++ (and C++ in general) by entering string values into a list, in a do-while loop, and then have them printed from the list in a for loop, but have run into an error:

```
error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'std::list<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>> *'
                                   to 'std::string*'
```

The error refers to this particular line:

```
output = &container[k];
```

I don't know how to fix this, or what I'm doing wrong. Nor do I know whether it's a problem with my understanding of lists, or whether I'm using pointers incorrectly.

I would appreciate it if any answers could be worded as simply as possible, thanks.

The rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void main()
{

int i = 0;
list<string> container[10];
string input, *output;  

do{
    cout << "enter a value for container location " << i << endl;
    cin >> input;
    container[i].push_back(input);
    i++;
}while (i < 10);

for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    output = &container[k];
    cout << "Value of container location " << j << " = " << *output << endl;
    k++;
}
}
```

Comment: `main` has return-type `int`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you clearly mean your type for `container` to be `vector<string>` without `[10]` or simply `string` (while keeping the array specification).

Comment: Following your advice, I changed the list to a vector, and removed all of the square brackets on each mention of container, except for the line where the error occurred and it works fine now.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pignaut,
    You are declaring an array (of size 10) of list of String, hence, each element of the array is a list of string. That's why this error.
   But, I think you want to declare a list of string.